# Is there a way to know that Stage Manager (multitasking is currently enabled) in Xamarin. Forms Programmatically?

Tags: ipad, xamarin.forms, appdelegate, ipados, ipados16

1. Is there a way to know that Stage Manager (multitasking is currently enabled) from Xamarin.Forms?
2. Is there a way to disable this programmatically
3. Can it be checked during application startup?

Comment: Hi @Ajay it's a Good question as Apple recently announced the StageManger feature, Even I'm checking the feasibility of getting this Programmatically! I hope we will get the answer!

Comment: are you using two accounts with the same name in order to comment on your own posts?

Comment: Comment and upvote, I suspect. If so, that is a violation of StackOverflow rules.